# Can I have a single Google Maps API key for all my apps without registering their package names?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have written an android library project that includes custom MapFragments, based on Google Maps for Android v2 API. In the Google APIs console, I have registered the library's package name with my debug/signed certificates.

I need to create various apps that use this library as common code base and I was wondering if there is a way to still use the MapFragments of the library, *without having to add each app's package name* in the Google APIs console. I need this because I want to automate app creation (with Jenkins) and I don't want any manual steps, like logging in to the APIs console and registering the package name.

So far, I haven't managed to find a way to do this. Wildcards don't work (e.g. having *com.mycompany.** as package name in the console), and if I don't explicitly register each app's package name, the map doesn't load.

Is it possible to somehow make the MapFragments look up the *library*'s single api key/package, instead of the app's?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's how to accomplish what you're trying to do when creating a new API key:

- Click create new Android key button
- Don't enter anything into the package names list
- Click create

Then you should see AndroidApps: Any app allowed, and be able to use that maps API key in all of your apps without any configuration on the APIs console.

Since you have probably already have entered the certificate fingerprints for each of your applications, just click Edit allowed Android apps, delete them all from the list, click update, and it should say any app is allowed to use that API key.

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't even thought of not adding any package! This is the correct answer I was looking for! **Thanks!**

Comment: Heh, no problem. I figured this out by accident

Comment: This saved me a load of work.  When you set up the api the language implies that a package is required when it isn't.

Comment: This isn't valid anymore. Could someone update the answer?

Comment: If you don't enter the restriction (the package name + SHA1) and then if key gets exposed to unauthorized people by decompiling the apk then they can use it in their apps and you will be charged for that key theft.

Answer (score 10):

It can answer for 2 ways

Can I have a single Google Maps API key for all my apps?

> Yes, you can
>        by register API Key with multiple lines by using enter, like this: 
>   [image]

but for this question
Can I have a single Google Maps API key for all my apps without registering their package names?

> No, you can't

*edit image for easier to read

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but of course this is not what I'm looking for. This is naturally the way I already register my keys, one for all apps. It's the "without registering every app's package" that is troubling me.

Comment: If you want to put it with 1 package for all (such like /*./*). It's impossible. By this package, Google can separate all app from developer so Google can collect money from developer, or corporate that using a huge load of Google API. Also, Developer could separate all of their app to avoid confuse from the same KEY

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. Registering takes like 15 seconds per app if you use the same key for all of them.

Comment: Right, I know that the process is very quick, but it would be hard to automate e.g. with Jenkins. I'll keep searching, and if I don't find anything, I guess I'll have to mark your answer as the correct one!

Comment: I don't know if this ever was true but for some years now it isn't. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start : "Note: When using the standard API, you can use same API key for your Google maps Android API apps and your Google Places API for Androidapps."

Answer (score 0):

No...  you have to specify package name. It identify your application registered with Map key

Comment: I don't know if this ever was true but for some years now it isn't. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start : "Note: When using the standard API, you can use same API key for your Google maps Android API apps and your Google Places API for Androidapps."