# Changing API Key Has No Effect

Tags: android, android-maps

**In messing around, I noticed that adding a dummy API Key to a working project's AndroidManifest.xml does not affect the project.** In fact, I added key "Asfasdfasdfasfa" which isn't even valid and the project **continues working.**

Could someone draw light on this issue? Is there caching going?

---

Console:

```
MY:SS:HA:1K:EY;com.company.myproject
MY:SS:HA:1K:EY;com.example.gmaptest
```

Working manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.myproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.company.myproject.MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="asdfadf22" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Posted, this exact manifest works.

Comment: Andddd now both work... and I can't break either of them....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this: [Can I have a single Google Maps API key for all my apps without registering their package names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233442/can-i-have-a-single-google-maps-api-key-for-all-my-apps-without-registering-thei).
To create an API key, you provide some information that include the package name of the app. That means you are trying to validate one of your apps with a key created with another package name, this could be the issue.

Comment: Hi Tobiel, I used that as reference earlier, in fact I also commented on it. Thank you for your answer though.