# Using the same Google Maps Api Key for multiples applications

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

The company I work for is developing an app builder to generate android apps.

With `gradle` is relatively easy achieve the automation at the chain build point. Reading from a JSON you can configure the main attributes of the app, such as package name, app name, ic launcher… before exporting the apk.

But the problem is that these apps automatically generated will use Google Maps Api v2. And as far as I know, there is no way to use a map without obtaining previously an api key. But in order to get this api key you must supply (among other things) the package name of the app, which defeats the whole purpose of the automation.

So, my question is if is there a way to use the same Google Maps Api Key across multiples applications. Or alternatively if someone knows about other maps-on line libraries that they have not such restriction.

Thanks.

Comment: you cannot use same key for different applications.As all package names are different.ref- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: Yeah, that's basic the problem xD But you know, there are out there some companies that generate that kind of app in an automated way. So... there must be a way to achieve it.

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: Well, I don’t use it. But it seems to me that this [app builder](http://www.mobincube.com) could do it.

Comment: Go through this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233442/can-i-have-a-single-google-maps-api-key-for-all-my-apps-without-registering-thei

Comment: Well, we'll try it. But it sounds crazy. Thanks ;)

Comment: Yes..I'm alsi going to try it now

Comment: You should make the client supply an api key that the client has regsitered or register an api key on behalf of the client.