# Android - googlemap not working in other person's device

Tags: android, google-maps

I got a google map key and applied in my Android Studio
It works well but problem occurred when I send my project to other person
Nothing shown on their map except the google map mark
I think the problem is on google map key...
Isn't possible to use google map in one person's key??
And what if I make the apk??

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the google maps api key is created with your computer SHA1, so your friend will need to create a new one. Or you can create a key without restrictions 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17372920/4849189

Answer (score 0):

if you generate release apk so you need to generate a google map Api key base on generated "keystore" (.jks file that you create it).
if you send debug apk to your friend it should work if work for you.
if you send all of source code to your friend and he/she run that project on device so as @Oscar Gallon said ,your friend should generate debug map Api key base on it's pc sha1.

NOTE: in some case when you generate release android googlemap key and project apk, you should add generated api key in manifest directly(not in res/value/... xml file that automatically generate).